# what is the maximum tasks for kafka streams on multiple topcis with different partition

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

- Suppose we have two input topics.  Topic1 has 2 partitions, and Topic2 has 4 partitions.
- We create the kafka stream application with thread number 1.

Question: what is the maximum number that we can run the stream application that all will be assigned a partition?

as for my understanding, it is decided by the maximum partition of input topics. that is 4.

while what I want to achieve is 6, that is the sum number of all topics' partition. do you know is this doable? Thanks.

Comment: I think the question is not clear to me. What number are trying to determine? "maximum number that we can run the stream application" what does this mean? Also, how are the two topics processed by the kafka streams application. By two independent topologies?

Comment: i mean only one stream pipeline/topology. one example simple processor/pipeline could be that it takes messages from source pattern topics and sink to another topic.  my question is what is the maximum effective running tasks/pipeline we can have.

Comment: It depends on the structure of your program... Each sub-topology is "scaled" independently. In the end, the number of _tasks_ that are created (which depends on the sub-topologies and number of input topic partitions per sub-topology) determine how many intances/threads you can utilize.

Answer (score 1):

The parallelism of a streams application is defined number of partitions in the input topic(s), you are correct. You cannot change this. A workaround would be to work with an intermediate repartition topic: you repartition the input topic into a new topic with 6 partitions, and then do the actual work with a parallelism of 6.

Comment: Thanks. this does be a workaround.it seems kafka consumer client API is able to set StickyAssignor to achieve it. while i am not sure why kafka stream do not support it.  refer: https://medium.com/streamthoughts/understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies-and-how-to-write-your-own-custom-assignor-ebeda1fc06f3